# Delegate not working, when using a modal presented NavigationController ( iOS 5 - Storyboard )

Tags: delegates, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder, ios5, segue

I have a problem with a protocol.

My "initial View Controller" is a Navigation Controller. On the root page i show an other Navigation Controller in which is View Controller embedded. onclick a segue should be fired...this works perfectly but the delegate method from the "ViewController" is never called.

The image I added is a example how I build the connection between the 2 NavigationControllers with the InterfaceBuilder in iOS 5.

[image]

MyViewController.h

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>

@required
- (void) myFunction:(NSString *)string;

@end

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <MyProtocol>

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<MyProtocol> delegate;

@end
```

MyViewController.m

```
#import "MyViewController.h"
@implementation PropertyController
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

- (void) myFunction:(NSString *)string {
    [_delegate myFunction:string];
}

- (IBAction) callDelegate:(id)sender {
     ![enter image description here][1][self myFunction:@"test"];
}
```

And this is the code for the ViewController which is showing the NavigationController from above

ViewController.h

```
#import "MyViewController.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MyProtocol>
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void) myFunction:(NSString *)string {
    NSLog(@"myFunction was called");
}

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    [((MyViewController *) segue.destinationViewController) setDelegate:self];
}

- (IBAction) showModalNavigationController {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"NameFromSegueInInterfaceBuilder" sender:self];
}
```

I cant find a solution for my problem.

I hope somebody can help me

thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of problems here:

1. In your storyboard screenshot, you have a second navigation controller. You should not not need to embed your PropertyController in a navigation controller. Instead, have the root view controller segue directly to the PropertyController. If for some reason you do need that navigation controller, then you would need to change your `prepareForSegue` implementation above, because `segue.destinationViewController` in this case points to the `UINavigationController`. So you would need to get that nav controller object, and then send `setDelegate` to the `rootViewController` of that nav controller object. But again, only if you decide to keep that navigation controller.
2. How does `MyViewController` relate to your `ViewController` and `PropertyController` classes? The `PropertyController` class (or a superclass) needs to have the `@property` and `synthesize` statements for the `delegate` property.

Comment: Hi, thank you but i need that second navigation controller. so i have to change the prepareForSegue implementation. how can i set the delegate from MyViewController there?

Comment: Since this is a common need when working with storyboards, I implement a category on `UIStoryboardSegue` for this. See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041237/how-to-set-the-delegate-with-a-storyboard/8041666#8041666) to another storyboard question.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now i set the delegate from the topViewController to self and now it works! :)       [((MyViewController *)(((UINavigationController *) segue.destinationViewController).topViewController)) setDelegate:self];

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same issue, to make it work, I found a work around which xcode does not really like, but it still is working though -->  setting your delegate as you do it, makes your navigation controller have your view as delegate, if you NSLog self.delegate in your destination controller it will be null. To prevent this do -->

```
self.delegate = self.navigationController.delegate;
```

in your destination controller (viewdidload), it will get the delegation you created on the navigation controller, and allow you yo use it in your destination controller

It is dirty but it's the only way I found. Hope it helps.