# 'Receiver (<ViewController:>) has no segue with identifier 'infoseg'

Tags: iphone, ios, uistoryboardsegue

Recently my app is crashing when the app switch to the next ViewController.

this is the `prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`

```
    ShowInfoViewController *secondViewController = (ShowInfoViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
```

this is how i call the method :

```
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"infoseg" sender:self];
```

in the interface builder i have a segue with the same identifier as well.

any idea?

this is the log's Print :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<ViewController: 0x1dda97d0>) has no segue with identifier 'infoseg''
```

*** First throw call stack:
(0x322982a3 0x31a6a97f 0x34fdbca9 0x1972f 0x1a7fb 0x57d73 0x56ff3 0x5a2f3 0x372c2ef5 0x372029f1 0x3720290d 0x355115df 0x35510ccb 0x35539133 0x321de74d 0x35539593 0x3549d15d 0x3226d683 0x3226cee9 0x3226bcb7 0x321deebd 0x321ded49 0x32f472eb 0x34e24301 0x17427 0x173c8) libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your destination viewcontroller is inside a navigationcontroller, you might want to take a look at this question: [How to set the delegate with a storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041237/how-to-set-the-delegate-with-a-storyboard).

Edit: from the error it looks like the segue you are trying to perform is not attached to the viewcontroller you are starting from. Try to remove the seque and drag it from the viewcontroller your code is in to the ShowInfoViewController inside interface builder.

Comment: Could you please share a bit more of your code? What kind of error is displayed in the console?

Comment: Edited my answer as well. I'm able to reproduce your issue locally: if you try to perform a segue that is not attached to the same viewcontroller your code is attached to, the error you are describing occurs. Let me know how you get on!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue - it turned out I had a trailing space on the segue identifier on the story board.

eg. 'SequeIdentifier ' - of course this is pretty hard to see in XCode

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue. Realized I was setting the root controller in AppDelegate.m and in Storyboard as well. Removed the code in AppDelegate.m and it fixed it.