# pass data between storyboard with tabBar and external xib

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, xib, segue

I want to pass data between storyboard with tabBar and external xib . 
I tried to use prepareforsegue but the method didn't call or if i define a segue this didn't recognize this .

my code is :

```
 UIStoryboard *storyborad = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
       UIViewController *view = [storyborad instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"<identifier>"];
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
     // [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"try" sender:self]; // tried to use performSegueWithIdentifier but this recognize identifier
```

and the prepareforsegue method code :

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

BIDViewController *viewControllerView = segue.destinationViewController;
viewControllerView.isViewPushed=1;
NSLog(@"prepareForSegue");
```

Comment: Have you set the identifier in the xib?

Comment: You have a storyboard and you want to push to a nib file, no? So you can use [self performSegueWithIdentifier@"try" sender:self] but you need to set that identifier ("try") in the destination nib. After you have set the identifier in the nib, prepareSegue function will be called.

Comment: yes but its goes like that : 
external nib --> view in storyboard 
so what i did was define (give them identifier) both the nib itself (in the storyboard) and the segue but this still wrote "Receiver (<BIDSettingViewController: 0x1eb3ee60>) has no segue with identifier"

Comment: Take a look of this thread because they had the same issue, and let us know: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996504/receiver-viewcontroller-has-no-segue-with-identifier-infoseg

Comment: This doesn't work .. i want to add something that could help 
the external nib  is outside storyboard ( its belong to class that have own nib file ) 
i succeed to open view in the storyboard but i need to pass data too
maybe i dont set the segue identifier right ?

Comment: Yes, check that you have set right the view controller in that view and the identifiers

Comment: can i set the view controllers ? if yes how i set identifier ?

Comment: Setting the view controllers is go to the view controller in your view and change custom class to your class, and set the identifier there as well. http://i.stack.imgur.com/EJJpo.png

Comment: this what i did , when i pushed this open the view and the data not pass ( i use in this : UIViewController *view = [storyborad instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myIdentifier"];
and than push the view ) 
but if i set segue identifier and use :
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegueIdentifier" sender:self]
this wrote the has no segue with identifier

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyborad = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *view = [storyborad instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"<identifier>"];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

Try this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyborad = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
BIDViewController *view = [storyborad instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myIdentifier"];
view.isViewPushed = 1;
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```

Comment: the view dont connection to the class that have this property

Comment: sorry for double post , but the problem still there

Comment: Can you check if view from BIDViewController is nil?

Comment: Put a breakpoint after init it and see what is the value for the view or NSLog(@"%@", view) after initialise it

Comment: its not nil . if i push the view i can pass data or i have prepareForSegue ?

Comment: someone have any idea what i need to do ?

Comment: You can pass data using push. How have you declared isViewPushed property in BIDViewController? Can you show that code?

Comment: in the BIDViewController.h : 
@property NSInteger isViewPushed;

in BIDViewController.m :
<
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
if(isViewPushed==1)
    {
        [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
        isViewPushed=isViewPushed*-1;
    }
}
>

Comment: Check before sending (before pushViewController and in viewDidload in BIDViewController if the memory address is the same, doing po view and po self

Comment: I not sure that i check it right , but they no have the save memory address

Comment: Do you have another view property in your class? Anyways, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926606/performseguewithidentifier-vs-instantiateviewcontrollerwithidentifier and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348109/how-can-i-manually-switch-between-uiviewcontrollers-in-storyboard

Comment: I have another view property in BIDViewController . the links not help so much because like i told you before , one view in storyboard and the second belong to class that have .h , .m and xid file (in the links they have 2 view in storyboard) i push the view that in storyboard from the class that have own xid file