# Modal segue not working from code

Tags: iphone, ios, modal-dialog, segue

I've already spent the whole day in an issue and did not find a solution yet. I have a UITabBarViewController and I am trying to fire off a modal segue from one of its tabs. I've already created the view I want to segue to, created the segue itself (from the tab's view controller to the target's view controller) and the identifier. In order to test my segue I created a UIButton in my tab and wrote the following code on its action:

```
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showProductInfo" sender:self];
```

The modal segue worked fine. But if I try to write the same code to be performed somewhere else (inside a specific method that is called after I receive a web service response) the segue simply does not work. I get the following error:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver () has no segue with identifier 'showProductInfo''**

This is driving me crazy! Any help is more then welcome.

Editting:

Some additional findings:

If I take off the performSegue from the method I am currently using (which by the way is called by DidFinishLoading) and put it on ViewDidLoad the segue is performed successfully.

Thinking that it could be a thread related issue I included the performSegue inside a dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()... But the error is the same !

Comment: Make sure you perform modal segues not in viewDidLoad but in viewDidAppear.  There's no view shown to show the modal until after viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 0):

If your destination viewcontroller is inside a navigationcontroller, then take a look at this question:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041237/how-to-set-the-delegate-with-a-storyboard
```

Furthermore, from the error it looks like the segue you are trying to perform is not attached

to the viewcontroller you are starting from. So,Try to remove the seque and drag it from the

viewcontroller.

Comment: Hi Vishal, I am not using navigationcontroller. Regarding the right attachment I did control+drag from the yellow box below my "from" view  to my destination view. This should connect the viewcontroller itself, right ?

Answer (score 0):

The current view controller must have been loaded from a storyboard. If its storyboard property is nil, perhaps because you allocated and initialized the view controller yourself, this method throws an exception.

Make sure you have Storyboard ID for your destination VC (in this example myViewController).

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"myStoryboard" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UIViewController *myViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```