# how to set delegate as self when we push controller using performseguewithidentifier when using storyboards

Tags: objective-c, swift

how to **set delegate as self** when we push controller using 
*performSegueWithIdentifier* when using storyboards

Comment: `prepare(for: segue)` is called before view controller is presented. Make necessary assignments there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the delegate with a storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041237/how-to-set-the-delegate-with-a-storyboard)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you can do it in the `prepareForSegue` method. The `destination` property of `UIStoryboardSegue` stores the VC that the segue is going to.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? YourVCClass {
        vc.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In objective C, yo can do it using prepareForSegue method

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"yoursegue"]) {

        // Set delegate here
        viewController.delegate = self;
        //Code For Navigating
        .....


    }
}
```